# Show a winform on the desktop background and only on the desktop background

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way so that a winform (VB.NET or C#) can be shown only on the desktop of a workstation? Has anyone tried to do this before? help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the form paint event:

```
    Me.SendToBack()
```